# amp - C++ Assistor

Tags: c++, c, visual-studio, pointers

Is it possible to specify parameters to an pointer with something called `&amp;` in C/C++?

Basically let's say I have a function:

```
int vba (unsigned long *a, unsigned long *b){.....}
```

Can I declare non-pointer values to the parameters using this mysterious `&amp;` call?
I am reading this book and the author is using it to do so, but he doesn't declare what
it is, or what it is in general. I googled "&amp C++ call" and I didn't get any results.

So then he specifies a non ptr assignment using it in anothe function like so:

```
int vca ()
{
    unsigned long c, d;
    vba(&amp;c, &amp;d);
   //etc ...
}
```

This is where I am confused, I don't know what just happened here, or what that call does, how did he assign a pointer to a non-pointer like that ... seems quite awesome though I never heard of it before. Anyone mind elaborating on what this is, or how it is possible?

Also when I put this into my code it says in the error log: "Intellisense: identifier "amp is undefined"? This is where I got really lost because the compiler highlights the `amp` call in blue, so how is it undefined?

Comment: This is probably the result of several generations of converting between formats, and somewhere along the line someone at the publisher pasted HTML into the book instead of text. It's fairly rare to pay for technical knowledge in proofreaders.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That is just HTML encoding for the `&` character. The website you got this from clearly got something wrong. Hm, I just reread your question and noticed that you're talking about a book. Doesn't really change anything other than make the mistake even more appalling.

Anyway, replace the `&amp;` with `&` and you'll be good to go.

Comment: That's really strange huh? How the author made a mistake like that in a book, yea I was really confused by it aswell. I actually though for a second there that I was going to learn something new today :( I guess I was wrong, thanks anyways!

Comment: Exactly. At first I thought: yeah, typical of a poorly-executed website, but a book? Many people are supposed to read those things before they come out. Props to them for doing a good job.

Comment: Haha, I guess I can throw this book away, if they're going to miss such a flimsy error.

Comment: @user3267146 I wouldn't throw it away just based on this. It could be an honest error, and it's very unlikely that the author saw the final result, much less had time to verify every detail, before it went to print. Look for any errata online first.